# How to filter a Dataframe in such a way to return a True or False to a certain condition in Pyspark?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a data frame that returns False or True to a specific condition, it will replace the built-in function `.all` in pandas. I provided an expected outcome. thanks in advance!

```py
schema = StructType([
StructField( 'vin', StringType(), True),StructField( 'age', IntegerType(), True),StructField( 'var', IntegerType(), True),StructField( 'rim', IntegerType(), True),StructField( 'cap', IntegerType(), True),StructField( 'cur', IntegerType(), True)
  ])

data = [['tom', 10,54,87,23,90], ['nick', 15,63,23,11,65], ['juli', 14,87,9,43,21]]

df=spark.createDataFrame(data,schema)

df.show()
>>>
+----+---+---+---+---+---+
| vin|age|var|rim|cap|cur|
+----+---+---+---+---+---+
| tom| 10| 54| 87| 23| 90|
|nick| 15| 63| 23| 11| 65|
|juli| 14| 87|  9| 43| 21|
+----+---+---+---+---+---+

col_2=['age','var','rim']

df=df.select(*col_2)
df.show()
>>>
+---+---+---+
|age|var|rim|
+---+---+---+
| 10| 54| 87|
| 15| 63| 23|
| 14| 87|  9|
+---+---+---+

df=df.filter(F.col(*col_2) ==10)
#Expected outcome:
>>>
+---===+------+------+
|age   |var   |rim   |
+------+------+------+
| True | False| False|
| False| False| False|
| False| False| False|
+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a comparison for each column and select all of them. `filter` is not needed.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.select([(F.col(c) == 10).alias(c) for c in col_2])

df2.show()
+-----+-----+-----+
|  age|  var|  rim|
+-----+-----+-----+
| true|false|false|
|false|false|false|
|false|false|false|
+-----+-----+-----+
```